# For...Next loop breaks when using Not() operator

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, iteration

I am running a for...next loop that checking whether entries in a dataset meet a certain condition (in this case IsNA). However, changing the if-then-else conditions within this loop to also check whether a condition is not met seems to break the for/next loop. I receive a Next without For error even though that element of the sub hasn't changed.

I'm lost as to why the it thinks there is no next in the for loop when that part of the code hasn't changed.

--Original Working Code--

```
Option Explicit
Dim i As Double
Dim a As Range
Public ssht As Worksheet
Public susht As Worksheet
Public mdsht As Worksheet
Public LastRow As Long
Dim testcell As Long


Public Sub MissingDataSetCopy()
'Part Bii
'Find rows with NA error
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim i, j As Integer
j = 4
'Finds current range on Summary worksheet
Set ssht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sandbox")
Set mdsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MissingData")
Set susht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("summary")
'Copies data to sandbox sheet as values

susht.UsedRange.copy
ssht.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)

LastRow = ssht.Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
Dim testcell As Double
Dim numchk As Boolean
'For...Next look call ISNUMBER test
For i = 860 To 874
     If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) Then
    mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i - 1 & ":G" & i - 1).Value
    j = j + 1
    mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
    j = j + 1
    mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i + 1 & ":G" & i + 1).Value
    j = j + 1
    End If
    Next i

Dim fnd As Variant
Dim rplc As Variant

fnd = "#N/A"
rplc = "=NA()"
mdsht.Cells.Replace what:=fnd, Replacement:=rplc, _
 LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, _
 SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

--Edit to If Statements--

```
For i = 860 To 874

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i - 1)) Then
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) And Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i - 1))) Then
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i - 1 & ":G" & i - 1).Value
        j = j + 1
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

    Next i
```

Comment: @Matteo NNZ spotted the issue (+1); also, you might find this useful when trying to find all cells with text: ssht.Range("B860:B874").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, xlTextValues).Select, than increase the the found range to include all columns up to H, and copy all data to an mdsht.Range offset by -856

Answer (score 2):

You need to close the second `If` block:

```
For i = 860 To 874

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i - 1)) Then
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If '<-- it was not closed
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) And Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i - 1))) Then
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i - 1 & ":G" & i - 1).Value
        j = j + 1
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

Next i
```

Or alternatively using the `ElseIf` keyword if the two conditions (at it seems) are excluding each other:

```
For i = 860 To 874

    If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) And Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i - 1)) Then
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
        j = j + 1

    ElseIf Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i)) And Not (Application.WorksheetFunction.IsNA(ssht.Range("B" & i - 1))) Then
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i - 1 & ":G" & i - 1).Value
        j = j + 1
        mdsht.Range("B" & j & ":H" & j).Value = ssht.Range("A" & i & ":G" & i).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: Legend! This worked perfectly. One last quick question, this script is extremely slow - I'm wondering whether its because I've declared a bunch of variables As Worksheet. Is there another way to do this that will be faster or is there is something else obviously making this script slow to execute?

Comment: Look into using `Application.ScreenUpdating` and setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before the loop and then back to `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` after the loop.